# C# Visual Studio 2010 - Import data from excel files into C# VS database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, excel, function

I have a project in c# vs2010 with a SQL Server database (3 tables)

I need to import data from two Excel files, one to fill `CapitalPlan`, the other to fill `MilestoneData` tables respectively.

I have been advised to fill this using VS 2010 tools (see view in erd diagram link), without using code in any of my C# forms - I just need to fill it with data so I can create and test some queries.

Please can anyone advise how I may go about doing this? Maybe creating a function in vs... I'm not entirely sure

Much appreciated

Images below may help:

ERD diagram

http://i1186.photobucket.com/albums/z373/barbsbargainsltd/erd_zps059d4dac.jpg

Excel CapitalPlan (to fill capital plan table)

http://i1186.photobucket.com/albums/z373/barbsbargainsltd/capplan_zps31bc1d6a.jpg

See comments for addition image (I don't have enough rep yet)

Comment: Excel MilestoneData (to fill milestone data table)
http://i1186.photobucket.com/albums/z373/barbsbargainsltd/msdata_zps9345be9a.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL Server management studio [Import wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) if it's one-off. If you need to run it programatically than consider creating SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use theses steps

• Services SQL Server DTS

• Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Integration Services (SSIS)

• The SQL Server linked servers

• SQL Server distributed queries

• Objects ADO (ActiveX Data Objects) and the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

• ADO and the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet 4.0

Link sample : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686/fr